# Unable to request a token, request fields empty

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openiddict

I'm trying to create an API for an SPA. I'm using the latest .NET Core, MVC and EF. I'd like to authenticate users using JWT, so I decided to use openiddict core. I've tried setting it up according to the examples at the [github page](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) and [this blog post](http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/). The problem is that I get "The specified grant type is not supported." when requesting a token.

Here's screenshot of postman request:
[image: Postman request]

Here's my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])
    );

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddOpenIddict<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .UseJsonWebTokens()
        .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
        .AllowPasswordFlow()
        .DisableHttpsRequirement()  // TODO: remove in production
        .AddEphemeralSigningKey();  // TODO: replace with a certificate, this should be used for development only
}
```

And the `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    // don't use identity as this is a wrapper for using cookies, not needed
    // app.UseIdentity();

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,  // TODO: remove, dev only
        Audience = "http://localhost:42443/",  // TODO: ???
        Authority = "http://localhost:42443/"  // TODO: ???
    });

    app.UseOpenIddict();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

I'm using the [`AuthorizationController`](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs) from the samples to handle the token requests. By observing the contents of the `request` argument of the `Exchange` method, which handles the `/connect/token` requests, I've discovered that it receives all the fields as nulls:
[image: Debugger]

I have no idea why. The postman request should be correct according to [this](http://kerryritter.com/authorizing-your-net-core-mvc6-api-requests-with-openiddict-and-identity/) and [this](http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/) blog post. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [mentioned in the samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/master/samples/PasswordFlow/AuthorizationServer/Startup.cs#L21-L24), you must register the OpenIddict MVC model binder to be able to use `OpenIdConnectRequest` as an action parameter.

Reference the `OpenIddict.Mvc` package and call `AddMvcBinders` and it should work:

```
services.AddOpenIddict<ApplicationDbContext>()
    // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
    // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
    // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
    .AddMvcBinders()

...
```

Comment: Ah, completely missed that part... I didn't even know there was another package required :) That was it! Thanks! :)

Comment: @HonzaKalfus note that this package is only needed if you want to be able to bind `OpenIdConnectRequest` parameters. You can still use `HttpContext.GetOpenIdConnectRequest()` if you prefer the low-level API.